# cutting a portion of url in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a few URLs which would need to cut and separate the first part of the each URL, i.e `example1.com`, `example2.com`, `example3.com` from each line and store in a variable

Contents in url.csv

```
https://example1.com/v1/test/f3de-a8c6-464f-8166-9fd4
https://example2.com/v1/test/14nf-d7jc-54lf-fd90-fds8
https://example3.com/v1/test/bd38-17gd-2h65-0j3b-4jf6
```

Script:

```
$oldurl = Import-CSV "url.csv"
$newurl = $oldurl.list -replace "https://"
```

This would replace `https://`, however the rest of each cannot be hard coded as those values can change.

What could be change code change required to cut anything from and after `/v1/` along with `https://`?

Answer (score 3):

```
$list = @(
    "https://example1.com/v1/test/f3de-a8c6-464f-8166-9fd4",
    "https://example2.com/v1/test/14nf-d7jc-54lf-fd90-fds8",
    "https://example3.com/v1/test/bd38-17gd-2h65-0j3b-4jf6"
)

$result = $list | %{
    $uri = [System.Uri] $_

    $uri.Authority
}

$result
```

See [System.Uri properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.100).aspx) to potentially assemble the information you need in your result list.

Answer (score 0):

This will cut off anything after "/v1/" and it self. Is that what you want?

```
 $string = "https://example1.com/v1/test/f3de-a8c6-464f-8166-9fd4"
 $string = $string -replace "https://" 
 $pos = $string.IndexOf("/v1/")
 $result = $string.Substring(0, $pos)
 $result

 Output: example1.com
```

Comment: This is how I would have done it but after reading @DavidBrabant's answer, that definitely is how OP *should* do it.